# Syntax Error near , and )

Tags: sql-server

This is my query but is returning error at last line ")" and Line 3 ","

```
select (present/total)*100 from( 
    (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo where Staff_Att_Status='Present' group by DHIS_Code) as present,
    (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo group by DHIS_Code) as total
    ) as "result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (present/total)* 100.00   --<-- Also use decimal here to get % values like 0.01 
FROM( 
    SELECT   --<-- You need a select key word here 
          (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo where Staff_Att_Status='Present' group by DHIS_Code) as present,
          (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo group by DHIS_Code) as total
    ) as "result"
```

Comment: it gives an error that Subquery returned more than one value

Comment: Well I don't know your data but you need to make sure that any sun-query in the select must return a scalar value.

Comment: sorry I meant to say sub-query not sun-query :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
select (present/total)*100 "result" from 
    (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo where Staff_Att_Status='Present' group by DHIS_Code) as present,
    (select count(Staff_Att_Status) from vu_StaffInfo group by DHIS_Code) as total
```

You are trying to aliasing the outer query which can't be used as inner alias.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this: (I have changed your subquerys to CTEs because they result on a very easy to read and understand syntax)

```
with present
as (
  select DHIS_Code, count(*) as count 
  from vu_StaffInfo where Staff_Att_Status='Present' 
  group by DHIS_Code
),

with total
as (
  select DHIS_Code, count(*) as count 
  from vu_StaffInfo 
  group by DHIS_Code
)

select total.DHIS_Code, (isnull(present.count,0) / total.count) * 100.00
from total
     left outer join present on present.DHIS_Code = total.DHIS_Code
```

You would want to return a percentage per DHIS_Code, seeing that you are grouping by it.

Also I have changed the count(Staff_Att_Status) by count(*), because you would want the count of rows on those datasets, and not the count of different Staff_Att_Status. Which, for example, will always be 1 on the **present** dataset, because you only have the "Present" status there.